# Scilab syntax error, unexpected end of line, expecting "," or ) its on line 14 and i dont why theres an error its correct thought

Tags: scilab

SO basically it keeps saying error at line 14 which is the "else" code is at i dont get it why it is synta error please help

```
clear
clc

function f=f(x)
    f = x^3 + 2*x^2 - 3*x -1
endfunction

disp ("sample input"): regulaFalsi (1,2,10^-4, 100)

function regulaFalsi(a, b, TOL, N)
    i = 1
    FA = f(a)
    finalOutput  =(i, a , b , a + (b-a)/2, f(a + (b-a) /2)
    
    printf ("%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s\n","n","a_n","b_n","p_n","f(p_n)")
    
    while (i <= N),
        p = (a*f(b)-b*f(a))/f(b) - f(a))
        FP = f(p)
        
        if (FP == 0 | aba (f(p)) < TOL) then
            break
        else 
printf("%-20.8g %-20.8g %-20.8g %-20.8g %-20.8g\n", i, a, b, p, f(p))
            end
            i = i + 1
            if (FA + FP > 0) then
                a = p
            else 
                b = p
            end
    end
```

I have been trying to fix this code for my assignment but i dont know why it keeps giving me syntax error

Comment: Is indentation important?

Comment: @BruceWayne: "only" for code style. Scilab is not python ;-)

Answer (score 1):

No indentation does not matter but you wrote

disp ("sample input"): regulaFalsi (1,2,10^-4, 100)

instead of

disp ("sample input"); regulaFalsi (1,2,10^-4, 100)

a colon : instead of a semi colon ;

Moreover an "end" is missing to close the  regulaFalsi function definition

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Serge's answer:

- regulaFalsi() is defined ''after'' the first call to it. Sure that this first call will fail.
- Although `finalOutput` is unused (and so likely useless), the definition  `finalOutput  =(i, a , b , a + (b-a)/2, f(a + (b-a) /2)`  misses a closing `)`. It is likely the origin of the error.
- f(): here it works, but in a more general way it is not a good idea to name the function's output with the same name as the function itself.
- putting `clear` at the head of your script(s) is not really a good idea. It is most often useless, and most often violent enough to erase useful objects, like libraries loaded on the fly, etc.

When you report an error, please report the full actual error message. It is most often more useful than only comments or "personal translation" of the error.